# Second out of three indented text blocks per line is not aligned

Tags: css, css-float

I have the following problem (the pen could be found here: http://codepen.io/rpkoller/pen/wJEhm?editors=110 ):

```
<div>
  <span class="ft-label">starts</span><span class="ft-labelinfo">Friday, 12.05.2014</span>
  <span class="ft-label">ends</span><span class="ft-labelinfo">Saturday,13.05.2014</span>
</div>

<div>
  <span class="ft-label">starts</span><span class="ft-labelinfoTRY">Friday, 12.05.2014</span><span class="ft-labelinfoTRY2">08:00-12:00</span>
  <span class="ft-label">ends</span><span class="ft-labelinfoTRY">Saturday,13.05.2014</span><span class="ft-labelinfoTRY2">09:00-14:00</span>
</div>
```

I want to indent the text blocks and have each aligned. In the first div block it works fine. I float the first "column" (`.ft-label`) with starts and end and then set a margin-left on the dates (`.ft-labelinfo`):

```
.ft-label {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
}

.ft-labelinfo {
  display:block;
  margin-left:5.5em;
  text-align:left;
}
```

When I apply that pattern to the second div accordingly with:

```
.ft-label {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
}

.ft-labelinfoTRY {
  display:block;
  margin-left:2.5em;
  text-align:left;
  float:left;
}

.ft-labelinfoTRY2 {
  display:block;
  text-align:left;
  margin-left:15em;
}
```

The times (`.ft-labelinfoTRY2`) are aligned properly but the dates (`.ft-labelinfoTRY`) aren't since they had to be floated and so their margin-left refers to the end of the ft-label spans which differ in length so they are not aligned. Is there a way to align all elements properly without using a grid solution or tables but stick to the pattern i've used? Or would it be better to use one of the aforementioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set a width to .ft-label and remove all margins. It will work just like you need it.